# How to get form data in Java Spark using Thymeleaf template engine?

Tags: thymeleaf, spark-java

I've built a simple application and now I'm trying to host attach it to a web server. I'm attempting to have a HTML form (using Thymeleaf) that the user enters their location in as text, and then my server will take and produce a result using that string. So to get started, I'm attempting to make a simple spark application that makes a home page with a "enter your location" form, that then gets the users input and does something with it. I can get the "entryMessage" displayed, as tutorials show, but how to get user data is proving difficult.

However, there is very little documentation on how this can be done with these two framworks. My attempt at what the code should look like is as follows. Note the middle post is just me trying to find ways to get the form data - none proved succesful

```
    ThymeleafTemplateEngine engine = new ThymeleafTemplateEngine();
    HashMap<String, String> userLocationMap = new HashMap<>();

    get("/home", (request, response) -> {
        userLocationMap.put("entryMessage", "Please enter your location");
        return new ModelAndView(userLocationMap, "home");
    }, engine);


   post("/home", (request, response) -> {
        System.out.println(request.toString());
        //System.out.println(request.body());
        //System.out.println(userResponse.location);
        //response.redirect("/locationAccepted");
        return userLocationMap.get("userLocation");
    });

    get("/locationAccepted", (request, response) -> {
        String location = request.queryParams("userLocation");
        return new ModelAndView(userLocationMap, "locationAccepted");
    }, engine);
```

with the following thymeleaf templates

home.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "http://www.thymeleaf.org/dtd/xhtml1-strict-thymeleaf-4.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<p> <span th:text="${entryMessage}"> default message </span> </p>
<form action="/locationAccepted" method="post">
    <input type="text" th:field="userLocation"/>
    <div class="button">
        <button type="submit">Send your message</button>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and locationAccepted.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "http://www.thymeleaf.org/dtd/xhtml1-strict-thymeleaf-4.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<p> <span th:text="${userLocation}"> default message </span> </p>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two bugs in your code, both in the HTML form:

1. In your Java code you're defining the route `"/locationAccepted"` as `GET`, but your form `method` attribute is `POST` => Change your form to `GET`.
2. If you want to get the form's `input` data it should have a `name` with value `userLocation`. `th:field` isn't translated to `name` (it's translated to `field` attribute which I'm not sure what it means).

So your form (after Thymeleaf) should look like this:

```
<form action="/locationAccepted" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="userLocation"/>
    <div class="button">
        <button type="submit">Send your message</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

And then `request.queryParams("userLocation")` will work like you wanted.